# Which muscle group am I missing in my workout routine?

Tags: muscle, strength-training, muscle-gain, running-training-plan, resistancetraining

Every day, I do this:

- Pull-ups.
- Suspension  dips.
- Leg lift (for abs).
- Side planks for abs.
- Biceps curls.
- Triceps curls.
- Chest-pull.
- Single-legged squat, up to full extension, including calf raise.
- Dumbbell shoulder press.

**Question:** which muscle group am I missing in my workout?

---

By reading comments/answers, reading articles, googling around, and using my logic: I am now considering this variation:

- Pull-ups.
- <s>suspension dips</s> forward-leaning suspension dips (to activate more chest, front shoulder).
- <s>Leg lift (for abs)</s> leg lift until torso curls (for better abs).
- Side planks for abs.
- <strike>biceps curls</strike> chin-ups.
- <strike>triceps curls</strike> straight-up suspension dips (to activate more triceps).
- Chest-pull (to activate rear shoulder).
- Single-legged squat, up to full extension, including calf raise.
- Dumbbell shoulder press.

To me, this is the most efficient full-body workout I know of to date.

Thoughts?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85147/discussion-on-question-by-caveman-which-muscle-group-am-i-missing-in-my-workout).

Answer (score 1):

Working out like this means you miss a lot of major movements. For example you have no squats, bench press, deadlift or shoulder press. These are the key compound movements in weight lifting.

The way you have your workout is really imbalanced. You're not hitting shoulders or your upper/lower back. On top of this continuously doing the same minimal exercises every day is going to provide minimal results. You need more variation in your workouts and to be more efficient.

Currently you're not hitting hamstrings, upper/lower back or full parts of shoulders and arms.

I recommended trying a "basic" split, Shoulders, Back, Chest, Arms, legs. To find a routine you enjoy I suggest looking online to see what you like the look of. Bodybuilding.com have a nice set of workouts and plans set by others that you can look at.

Comment: I just fixed a typo, and added dumbbell shoulder press (I forgot to add this).  I am surprised, how do you thin that I lack squats, benchpress, when I have similar ones, such as single-legged squat, and suspension dips (which works chest and triceps muscles).  Kindly clarify this.  Also, kindly cite a source for the "you need more variation in your workouts to be more efficient".

Comment: @caveman on top of this, only training the same movements every day increases the risk of injury. As you'll constantly be hammering the exact same muscle each and every day

Comment: I do my pullup using the palm-facing-front position, and my biceps curls, I twist the dumbbell.  Thoughts about which ones am I missing here?  E.g. at some point it looks like hammer curl, but as I raise it, I twist it and it becomes flat.  As for shoulders, isn't this attacking all 3 shoulder muscle:  dips attacks front shoulder, press attacks mid one, chest pull attacks the rear one.  Thoughts on the correctness of this?  Also got a study citation or that daily workout on same muscle group is more harmful than good?

Comment: @caveman That's just a normal good form bicep curl. You're not working anything else but your short head on your bicep. One exercise for each is bare minimum for making gains on a muscle, your body will adapt to it.  Your pullups don't work your back still, that's one of the key components of your body. They'll work your lats.

Comment: If you're not going to accept the advice why ask on a forum, just go look for the scientific data yourself, do your research as you're basically saying I'm doing this, I know it's wrong but I don't want to find evidence for it myself

Comment: So.. pullup + biceps curls = ony works out a single biceps muscle out of 3 (short-head brachii)?  Any link for me to read about?  I am really confused about which muscle for which movement.

Comment: I found this site, but it does not specify the specific sub-muscles within the biceps group https://musclewiki.org/

Comment: @caveman https://www.bodybuilding.com/content/two-heads-are-better-than-one-5-moves-for-biceps.html this is a link but it only is for a bicep workout, theres one for tricep in recommended. This is the reason why you should train a normal split rather than the routine you are following now

Comment: Thank you.  So, I guess, what activates the shorthead is the wide grip.  I am considering to do chin-ups with wide grip to achieve this.  Thoughts?  I have also updated my routine above.